# Not able to see the output messages of the tasks performed in celery-rabbitMQ combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pycharm, celery

I am trying out celery and rabbitMQ combinations for asynchronous task scheduling, below is the sample program I tried on Pycharm IDE....Everything seems to be working but I am not able to see the return value from the tasks.

I am also monitoring the rabbitMQ management console , but still not able to see the return value from the tasks.

I dont understand where I am going wrong,this is my first attempt at celery and RabbitMQ

I have created a tasks.py file with 2 sample tasks(with proper decorators assigned) and returning a value for each task.

I have also started teh RabbitMQ server (using {`rabbitmq-server start`} command).

Then I have started the celery worker, command used : {`celery -A tasks --loglevel=info`}

Now, when I am trying to execute these tasks using delay() method, the command ({`reverse.delay('andy')`}) is running and I am getting , something like this, but I am not able to see the returned value.

```
from celery import  Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker= 'amqp://localhost//', backend='rpc://')

@app.task
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: Where would you like to _see the return value_? Could you post the code of calling the task and accessing the return value?

Comment: I wanted to see the return value in the console where I am running the celery worker.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have figured out the issue... It seams the latest versions of celery don't go well with windows. To fix this issue, I have installed 'eventlet' package and it takes care of the rest.

One thing to note is that, we need to start the celery worker using eventlet support, PFB the command:

```
celery -A <module_name> worker -loglevel=info -P eventlet
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return value from task [by using the `result` property](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.result).  The syntax below is in python3 with type hinting so that you can follow along with what is going on.

```
import time
from celery.result import AsyncResult

result: AsyncResult = reverse.delay('andy')
task_id: str = result.id

while not result.ready():
    time.sleep(1)
    result = AsyncResult(task_id)
if result.successful():
   return_value = result.result
```

n.b., the above is a naive example because in a production environment, you typically don't busy wait like we did here.  Instead the client issues periodic polls checking whether the status is ready and, if not, returns control to some other portion of the code (like a UI with a spinner).